# Find Subsequence in a String

Tags: java, character-encoding, subsequence

I have been solving this set of a challenge on Hackerrank, link : [Hackerrank in a String](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/hackerrank-in-a-string/problem?utm_campaign=challenge-recommendation&utm_medium=email&utm_source=7-day-campaign)

I have come up with my Algo which goes like this :

> 1. To check whether it has atleast two a's, r's and k's according to the hackerrank string
> 2. Check that it contains following chars h, a, c, k, e, r, n, k
> 3. let p[0], p(1), p[2].....,p[9] be the respective indices of h, a, c, k, e, r, r, a, n, k in string . If p[0] < p(1) < p[2] < .... < p[9] is true, then contains hackerrank.

I know is very bad, and the output is also not coming due to this error : `Terminated due to timeout`

**CODE:**

I have a method named `hackerrankInString(String s)`, it returns "YES" or "NO" string

```
// Complete the hackerrankInString function below.
static String hackerrankInString(String s) {
  int countR = 0, countA = 0, countK = 0;
  //for reading multi-line inputs, it will perform operation individually 
  // on the inputs
  while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
    for(int i=0; i < s.length(); i++){
      if(s.charAt(i) == 'r')
        countR++;

      if(s.charAt(i) == 'a')
        countA++;

      if(s.charAt(i) == 'k')
        countK++;
    }

    //It should atleast have two As, two Rs, and two Ks
    if(countR >= 2 && countA >= 2 && countK >= 2){
      //If the string contains hackerrank
      if(s.contains(Character.toString('h')) && s.contains(Character.toString('a'))  && s.contains(Character.toString('c')) && s.contains(Character.toString('k')) && s.contains(Character.toString('e')) && s.contains(Character.toString('r')) &&    s.contains(Character.toString('n'))){
          if((s.indexOf('h') > s.indexOf('a')) && (s.indexOf('h') > s.indexOf('c')) && (s.indexOf('h') > s.indexOf('k')) && (s.indexOf('h') > s.indexOf('e')) && (s.indexOf('h') > s.indexOf('r')) && (s.indexOf('h') > s.lastIndexOf('r')) && (s.indexOf('h') > s.lastIndexOf('a')) && (s.indexOf('h') > s.indexOf('n')) && (s.indexOf('h') > s.lastIndexOf('k'))){
              if((s.indexOf('a') > s.indexOf('c')) && (s.indexOf('a') > s.indexOf('k')) && (s.indexOf('a') > s.indexOf('e')) && (s.indexOf('a') > s.indexOf('r')) && (s.indexOf('a') > s.lastIndexOf('r')) && (s.indexOf('a') > s.lastIndexOf('a')) && (s.indexOf('a') > s.indexOf('n')) && (s.indexOf('a') > s.lastIndexOf('k'))){
                  if((s.indexOf('c') > s.indexOf('k')) && (s.indexOf('c') > s.indexOf('e')) && (s.indexOf('c') > s.indexOf('r')) && (s.indexOf('c') > s.lastIndexOf('r')) && (s.indexOf('c') > s.lastIndexOf('a')) && (s.indexOf('c') > s.indexOf('n')) && (s.indexOf('c') > s.lastIndexOf('k'))){
                      if((s.indexOf('k') > s.indexOf('e')) && (s.indexOf('k') > s.indexOf('r')) && (s.indexOf('k') > s.lastIndexOf('r')) && (s.indexOf('k') > s.lastIndexOf('a')) && (s.indexOf('k') > s.indexOf('n')) && (s.indexOf('k') > s.lastIndexOf('k'))){
                        if((s.indexOf('e') > s.indexOf('r')) && (s.indexOf('e') > s.lastIndexOf('r')) && (s.indexOf('e') > s.lastIndexOf('a')) && (s.indexOf('e') > s.indexOf('n')) && (s.indexOf('e') > s.lastIndexOf('k'))){
                            if((s.indexOf('r') > s.lastIndexOf('r')) && (s.indexOf('r') > s.lastIndexOf('a')) && (s.indexOf('r') > s.indexOf('n')) && (s.indexOf('r') > s.lastIndexOf('k'))){
                                if((s.lastIndexOf('r') > s.lastIndexOf('a')) && (s.lastIndexOf('r') > s.indexOf('n')) && (s.lastIndexOf('r') > s.lastIndexOf('k'))){
                                    if((s.lastIndexOf('a') > s.indexOf('n')) && (s.lastIndexOf('a') > s.lastIndexOf('k'))){
                                        if(s.indexOf('n') > s.lastIndexOf('k')){
                                            return "YES";
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return "NO";
}
```

Please help me with this, I want to learn two thigs,

- How to solve this challenge
- How to solve my third algo statement efficiently

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of a regex to solve the problem:

```
static String hackerrankInString(String input) {
    final String regexHack = ".*h.*a.*c.*k.*e.*r.*r.*a.*n.*k.*";
    return input.matches(regexHack) ? "YES" : "NO";
}
```

Call it using :

```
System.out.println(hackerrankInString("hhaacckkekraraannk"));  // YES
System.out.println(hackerrankInString("hackerworld"));         // NO
```

You can try out the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/uq6r5v/1).

Comment: I found this solution suitable, but since I don't know how this works. Could you please provide a description of this works? I need to learn this technique, it will definitely help me in the long run.

Comment: If you click the link you will get an explanation for the regex on the right handside. Are you asking about *how* regex works or how the solution works with regex?

Comment: **I'm asking both Nicholas.** It is just a simulator or an online regex expression checker. I really need to understand this stuff. Shall I start learning regex?

Comment: Regex is always helpful. In this answer, we are checking whether the input *String* matches the regex. In lay man terms the regex is just making sure that *your* String will contain at minimum `hackerrank`. If true, it return "YES" else it returns "FALSE". The `.*` matches anything that lies between `h`, `a`, `c`..... `n`, `k`

Comment: Any good website to learn about regex **(for noobs)** Nicholas?

Comment: Plenty of sites online. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions) is also a good place to start.

Comment: Yeah, will do in a moment. Just one more question, could you please tell me why every time we have done `*.` with every single word?

Comment: That is to denote that there can be *any* number of characters between *each* alphabet. You can play around with the regex in the link of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Had not many time to check, but can look something like that

```
public static String solve(String startWord, String givenWord) {
    for(int i = 0; i < startWord.length(); i++) {
        String letter = startWord.substring(i, i + 1);
        int index = givenWord.indexOf(letter);
        if(index == -1) {
            return "NO";
        } else {
            givenWord = givenWord.substring(index + 1, givenWord.length());
        }
    }

    return "YES";
}
```